# Argparse: how to distinguish between arguments for parsers and subparsers

Tags: python, argparse

I want to use python-argparse with arguments and positional arguments. Say I have my script  on a commandline (which is just a simple&stupid example), this is my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--verbose', action='store_true')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='command', dest='command')
cmd1_parser = subparsers.add_parser('command1')
cmd1_parser.add_argument('--verbose', action='store_true')

args = parser.parse_args()

print args
```

Now I call this script like this:

```
~ $ myscript --verbose command1 --verbose
Namespace(command='command1', verbose=True)

~ $ myscript command1 --verbose
Namespace(command='command1', verbose=True)

~ $ myscript --verbose command1
Namespace(command='command1', verbose=True)
```

Now as you can see I always get the same Namespace-object, and cannot distinguish if the verbose command is a regular parameter or a subparser parameter.
But I need that to handle these parameters separately.
What would be an easy way (with minimum code efforts) to do that?

**EDIT**:

I filed an issue inside the Python stdlib issue tracker:
http://bugs.python.org/issue15327

Comment: Subquestion: where do I file issues for argparse?

Comment: It's in the standard library, so bugs go to http://bugs.python.org/. For a feature request, though, you should use python-list or python-ideas; see http://docs.python.org/devguide/communication.html.

Comment: I think this is a great question.  It seems like subparsers should (optionally) return a Namespace within a Namespace, but apparently they don't work like that.  Additionally, I'm a little surprised that the dest keyword to `add_subparsers` actually does something.  (it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your subparser's add_argument call to this:

```
cmd1_parser.add_argument('--verbose', action='store_true', dest='cmd1_verbose')
```

This will result in your first example returning:

```
~ $ myscript --verbose command1 --verbose
Namespace(cmd1_verbose=True, command='command1', verbose=True)
```

Comment: This works well as long as there aren't too many overloaded commandline arguments.

Comment: I added a metavar-param to the add_argument so that the argparse-help does not print CMD1_VERBOSE:
`cmd1_parser.add_argument('--verbose', action='store_true', dest='cmd1_verbose', metavar='VERBOSE')`

Answer (score 4):

Here's a little something I hacked together.  I would almost guarantee it isn't bug free, but it worked on this simple test.

```
import argparse

class _Action(object):
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master=master
    def add_parser(self,name,**kwargs):
        self.master.subparsers[name]=subParserEnabler()
        return self.master.subparsers[name]

class subParserEnabler(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.subparsers={}
        argparse.ArgumentParser.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

    def add_subparsers(self,**kwargs):
        return _Action(self)

    def parse_args(self,args,**kwargs):
        args=list(args)
        for k in self.subparsers.keys():
            if k in args:
                break
        try: 
            i=args.index(k)
            output=argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args(self,args[:i],**kwargs)
            o1=argparse.Namespace()
            setattr(output,k,o1)
            self.subparsers[k].parse_args(args[i+1:],namespace=o1)
        except:
            output=argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args(self,args,**kwargs)
        return output

parser = subParserEnabler()
parser.add_argument('--verbose', action='store_true')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='command',dest='command')
cmd1_parser = subparsers.add_parser('command1')
cmd1_parser.add_argument('--verbose', action='store_false')

args = parser.parse_args("--verbose command1 --verbose".split())
print args
```

It's still missing aliases and the help formatting is probably wrong...but at least it provides the output I wanted.  Ultimately, John Gaines Jr's answer is probably a lot simpler than mine though.